# cannot GET // React

Tags: node.js, react

Criamos nosso primeiro projeto em React, local tudo funciona normal..

Quando hospedamos na web ... o sistema entra no endereço por exemplo  https://www.dominio.com/painel_teste

Nesse momento aparece a tela de login (é colocado usuário e senha )  e entra na tela do sistema (ok) no endereço   https://www.dominio.com/painel_teste/termometro ....

Quando se tenta atualizar a pagina ...F5 ...  o endereço mantem o mesmo porém aparece na tela a mensagem

cannot GET //termometro ...

como se fosse algum problema de rota ....

Já tentamos diversas alternativas e todas sem sucesso....

Algumas considerações
1 ) Gerei o build do projeto
2 ) Subi a pasta build para a pasta painel_teste (no servidor)
3 ) Criei um arquivo de configuração   "painel_teste.js"  com a seguinte configuração

```
var http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const baseDir = `${__dirname}/build/`
app.use(express.static(`${baseDir}`))
app.get('/painel_teste', (req, res) => res.sendfile('index.html' , { root : baseDir } ))

const port = 21164;
app.listen(port)
```

4 ) Arquivo de routes

```
const Routes = () => (

<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/painel_teste" component={Login} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/painel_teste/termometro" component={TermometroRRC} />
       <Route exact path="/logout" component={Logout} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

);

Aguardo sugestões ....

Answer (score 0):

Talvez seja uma má configuração no servidor, por exemplo ao utilizar o nginx, é necessário adicionar ao arquivo de configuração:

`location / {
    root /folder/subfolder/build;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}`

Onde esse `try_files` refere-se, que caso a rota não esteja configurada no servidor, ela irá redirecionar a página principal, onde a mesma irá efetuar toda a parte de rotas da aplicação.

Outro exemplo é uma aplicação hospedada no Netfly, onde é necessário criar um arquivo `_redirects` com o conteúdo  `/*    /index.html   200`, dentro da pasta `public`, antes de efetuar o build da aplicação React.